# How to receive errors while downloading a file using axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, axios

My code:

rest client:

```
return axios.get(url, {
    responseType: 'arraybuffer'
});
```

handling response:

```
  const link = document.createElement('a');
            link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
            link.target = "_blank"; 
            link.click();
```

works nicely if there are no errors on the server side.
However, when there is an error in the server API, I get no details of it, because of the response type being `arraybuffer`.

```
    .catch((error) => {
        dispatch(showError("An Error Occured", error)); //error does not contain the expected details
    });
```

I tried not setting the arraybuffer type, instead using the TextDecoder, however the result pdf seems to be corrupt (empty display).

How can I modify the existing setup in order to be able to receive details in case an error occurs?

**Edit: Solution:**
OK, I got it, I can decode the error information from the error.data:

```
var data:any = JSON.parse(new TextDecoder().decode(error.data));
```

and then use the error code & message.

Comment: i think you have a problem with empty array in result? so, it's easy !!! don't download the file when the result is `[]`

Answer (score 0):

I know it is old question but found it while very long looking for solution to download pdf file in Vue from Laravel based api endpoint with laravel-snappy package. Maby it will help someone:

This is my code in api ednpoint that downloads file with specific name:

```
$pdf = App::make('snappy.pdf.wrapper');
    $data = Blade::render($template->content, compact('contract'));
    $pdf->loadHTML($data)
        ->setOption('encoding', 'utf-8')
        ->setOption('margin-top', 20)
        ->setOption('margin-right', 20)
        ->setOption('margin-bottom', 20)
        ->setOption('margin-left', 20);
    return $pdf->download('document_' . sha1(time()) . '.pdf');
```

And if something is wrong returning some message:

```
return response()->json([
                'message' => 'Can't generate contract......'
            ], Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
```

Everything seemed to be fine but problem is with getting filename and 400 error in axios because of responseType: 'arraybuffer' or 'blob' that are not standard json responses, so this is my solution in Vue or JS based:

```
            axios.get(endpoint,{responseType: 'arraybuffer'})
            .then(response => {
                //Get filename from response headers
                let contentDisposition = response.headers["content-disposition"];
                let fileName = contentDisposition.split("filename=")[1];
                //Download file
                let blob = new Blob([response.data], { type: 'application/pdf' })
                let link = document.createElement('a')
                link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
                link.download = fileName
                link.click()
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                //Handle error for responseType: 'arraybuffer'
                if (error instanceof AxiosError && error.response) {
                    let message = JSON.parse(new TextDecoder().decode(error.response.data)).message;
                    this.makeToast(message, "danger");
                }
            })
```